# Aspx dropdownlist not displaying top value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an aspx page (C# code page). I have some hard coded dropdownlists and for some reason they are not displaying the top list item (value). I added an extra top list item (value) and now the correct values display for the values already in it, but that extra one does not display.

The only functionality I do with my dropdownlists in my C# code is to hide or show them. And then do validation or not based on the selected value.

My aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAction" runat="server" Visible="True" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="25px" Width="149px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Select">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

C# Code:

```
ddlAction.Visible = false;
ddlAction.Visible = true;
```

I use dropdownlist's regularly and have never had this problem before. Does anyone have any ideas what the issue could be?

UPDATE TO THIS ISSUE:

I added my items in my C# code as per Rahul. Did a quick test and it worked.
Now this morning, I am once again getting blanks for the first item ("Please Select").

Aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAction" runat="server" 
 AppendDataBoundItems="True" Height="27px" Width="159px">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

C# code:

```
ddlAction.Visible = true;
ddlAction.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ddlAction.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select","Select"));
ddlAction.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Yes", "Yes"));
ddlAction.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("No", "No"));
ddlAction.DataBind();
```

Rendered source code:

```
  &nbsp;<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlAction" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAction" style="height:27px;width:159px;">
<option selected="selected" value="Select"></option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `AppendDataBoundItems = true` property of DropSownList into your .aspx page.

you may also assign value from code behind as well like

```
ddlAction.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. While AppendDataBoundItems didn't work in the aspx, if I took your suggestion and tried assigning the values in the code right after I make the list visible - that works perfectly. Thank you very much. This fixed this issue.

Comment: Assigning value from code behind is what fixed this issue. Thank you Rahul.

Comment: This morning it's back to displaying the blank again. See my amended question for the update.

Comment: clean your project and build it again.

Comment: I tried that, using the procedure explained on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx but it's still not displaying that top value.

Answer (score 1):

use `AppendDataBound = true` in your aspx coe.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAction" AppendDataBound = true runat="server" Visible="True" Height="25px" 
                            Width="149px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Select">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

### Edit 1

More detail about [List Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
 <asp:ListItem Value="-2" Text="Please Select"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: Thanks Shekhar. I tried that. It didn't accept AppendDataBound but had AcceptDataBoundItems so I added that.

And I'm still getting my top item showing blank instead of it's value. So I think it must be a different problem.

Comment: You have not used values in your list item?

Comment: The top item has a value and that is the one that is not showing. I will try adding the value for the others but the value and the text is the same so I didn't think it was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you declare your `DropDownList` `ListItems` using its internal properties and defining what `ListItem` must be the selected one:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAction" runat="server" Visible="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="25px" Width="149px">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value="Select" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

It's the way `ASP.NET` uses to work and will return you the right selected value on the server side on postbacks.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Then I renamed and started from scratch using all the advice everyone has given. And no - it doesn't show the top value. Interestingly I had not deleted the renamed one or hidden it. That one works perfectly. So it's something to do with the "visible" property messing it up.

Comment: Can you show us what is the HTML being rendered by the `ASP.NET`? Then we may have a clue about how it's behaving...

Comment: Alexandre, I took Rahul's advice and just did the AppendDataBoundItems in my C# code and then did a DataBind. That solved my issue.

Would you like me to uncomment the fix and then run it so that I can show you the HTML being rendered when it doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, I saw you solve the problem. That's great.
What would be nice is to see what `ASP.NET` was rendering before and after problem has being solved.

Comment: Alexandre, I took out the fix and ran it. Checked what was rendered. All values are rendered but first one displays as a blank. And now this morning the solution that worked is no longer working. Starting to think I've got a bloody gremlin in my laptop.

Comment: I've amended the question with code updates plus the rendered source code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't have to use nor the `DataBind()` method neither set the `AppendDataBoundItems`, because, you already inserted the `ListItems` and you aren't loading options from a database!

I think you need to tell what `ListItemIndex` is the selected one by seting a value to the `DropDownList.SelectedIndex` property.

EDIT

Also, try to read to MSDN documentation about the [AppendDataBoundItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and the [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.databind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I'll try that and get back to you a bit later once I've read through that documentation and then changed the code and tested.

Comment: Alexandre, I just read the documentation and tried taking out the DataBind and AppendDataBoundItems. Then I selected a value using the SelectedIndex property. That didn't work.

I gave up and then created a lookup table (which I don't generally do if I only have a yes/no dropdown) for my values. That works perfectly (tested 3 times and each time it works).

I have dropdowns in every website I have built. I have no clue what went wrong with this one as I originally did it as I always do and then amended to try different things (according to advice I was given here).